# Getting LinkedIn details

Tags: python, error-handling, linkedin

Each field is prone to throw an exception if not found. If one element not found, then the next should be checked. I have put each element in a separate try/catch. Is this a correct approach or can it be optimized?

```
def getLinkedinDetails(self, gearman_worker, gearman_job):
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS('/usr/local/bin/phantomjs')
    user_input = gearman_job.data
    user_input_list = user_input.split()
    if len(user_input_list) == 2:
        first = user_input_list[0]
        last = user_input_list[1]
    elif len(user_input_list) == 1:
        first = user_input_list[0]
        last = ''
    print "https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first="+first+"&last="+last
    driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/pub/dir/?first="+first+"&last="+last)
    driver.set_window_size(1124, 850)
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
        wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "content-wrapper")))
    except:
        "print timed out"
    final_result = []
    for s in driver.find_elements_by_class_name('vcard'):
        result = {}
        try:
            name = s.find_element_by_class_name('given-name').text
            result['name'] = name
            surname = s.find_element_by_class_name('family-name').text
            result['surname'] = surname
            fullname = name + ' ' + surname
            if user_input.strip() == user_input.strip():
                pass
            else:
                continue
            title = s.find_element_by_class_name('title').text
            result['title'] = title
            location = s.find_element_by_class_name('location').text
            result['location'] = location
            profile_url = s.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
            result['profile_url'] = profile_url
        except:
            pass
        try:
            industry = s.find_element_by_class_name('industry').text
            result['industry'] = industry
        except:
            pass
        try:
            current = s.find_element_by_class_name('current-content').text
            result['current'] = current
        except:
            pass
        try:
            past = s.find_element_by_class_name('past-content').text
            result['past'] = past
        except:
            pass
        try:
            education = s.find_element_by_class_name('education-content').text
            result['education'] = education
        except:
            pass
        try:
            img = s.find_element_by_class_name('photo').get_attribute('src')
            result['img'] = img
        except:
            pass
        print result
```

Comment: See [why `except: pass` is a bad programming practice](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21553327/216074). You might want to check whether `find_element_by_class_name` actually returns anything instead. And you can always write a function instead of duplicating code.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. For examples of good titles, check out [Best of Code Review 2014 - Best Question Title Category](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/q/3883/23788) You may also want to read [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/41243).

Comment: The title was better _before_ it was changed. It indicated the problem, was specific and conscience, while new title is meaningless and has no relevance to the problem. Whether this code is trying to fetch LinkedIn details or to bake some cookies is inconsequential, the problem is in the repeating `try ... except` statement. I don't feel like it is my place to revert the edits, but I'd support nlper in doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The biggest problem is what [@SeanPerry](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/35547/sean-perry) and [@Ethan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/53251/ethan-bierlein) already pointed out:
all those try-except should go in a helper method.

And if we knew what exception you're catching there,
we might be able to tell how to write that better.
I'm wondering if a try-except is really the right solution there,
instead of using conditions.

---

Unless I'm missing something, this is utterly meaningless code that should have been removed before posting for review:

> ```
> if user_input.strip() == user_input.strip():
>     pass
> else:
>     continue
> ```

---

This is pretty strange code as well:

> ```
> try:
>     wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
>     wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "content-wrapper")))
> except:
>     "print timed out"
> ```

What is the `"print timed out"` doing in the `except`?
You know that will do nothing at all.

---

A few problems with this part:

```
if len(user_input_list) == 2:
    first = user_input_list[0]
    last = user_input_list[1]
elif len(user_input_list) == 1:
    first = user_input_list[0]
    last = ''
```

The problems:

- Missing `else`. Would the program work if `user_input_list` is empty?
- What if the length of `user_input_list` is 3 or greater?
- Both branches set `first` to the same value: that statement could as well be outside of the conditions
- The length of `user_input_list` is calculated twice. It would be better to calculate only once and save in a local variable

Here's a simple alternative implementation works around these issues in a lazy way:

```
user_input_list = user_input.split() + ['', '']
first, last = user_input_list[:2]
```

Answer (score 4):

## Proper error handling

***Never, ever*** do something like this:

```
try:
    ...
except:
    ...
```

It's a horrible idea, for a couple of reasons:

1. It will catch **every error**, even the ones you don't want to catch.
2. Rare, nasty errors like a `SystemError`, will be caught, and ignored as well. Stuff like `NameError`s, and even `SyntaxError`s will be caught.
3. It's not very clear to the reader of your code, what you're trying to prevent.

For more info, see [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice).

---

## Proper error logging

You have a lot of `except: pass`es in your code. It's *never* helpful to the user, or even the programmer in some cases, if you don't get output when an error is caught. You could use the `logging` module, or write error output to a file, while informing the user in some way, that something went wrong.

---

## Style

From looking at your code, you only appear to have two style violations:

1. Function names should be in `snake_case`.
2. Lines should be limited to 79/80 characters.

If you want to be sure, you can always check [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), Python's official style guide, to ensure that everything is correctly styled.

Comment: -1 for doubly bad advice: `print` is for developers during debugging, one should use `logging` for proper logging. Never use an extra function to throw errors, the location of the error is probably the most important information the error can carry, by defining a function to throw an error you move that info to an unrelated place.

Comment: @wvxvw There, I've removed those

Answer (score 2):

First, everything Ethan said. Well, maybe not the 80 chars thing :-)

First, separate the web request from the response processing. This makes it much easier to test and re-use.

Second, perhaps a simple wrapper function would make this code a little easier to manage?

```
def get_elements(web_obj, names):
    results = []
    try:
        for name in names:
            element = web_obj.find_element_by_class_name(name).text
            results.append(element)
    except ......:  # not sure the right exception here
        # respond. Log, raise again, ignore

given, family = get_elements(s, ['given-name', 'family-name'])
# use given, family
title = get_elements(s, ['title'])
# use title
location = get_element(s, ['location'])
# further process for the link
```

In the literature this style is sometimes referred to as an embedded domain specific language or eDSL. Basically you make a handful of simple commands and build a more complex program from them. The practical point is you make layers in your code which allow you to focus on each layer as needed. Again, this makes testing easier.

Comment: Your code is not equivalent to OPs code. It will bail out after encountering the first error, while OPs code will continue to try other options. If you want to make it equivalent, you need to move the `try ... except` inside the loop.

Comment: Fair but the whole handling of exceptions is questionable currently. But yes, moving my try handling in would be closer to current behavior.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I believe that the reason you have this many almost identical `try ... except` statements is that the document you select from doesn't always contain all the nodes you hope it does. The solution for this? - Try building an XPath expression that selects the nodes you need. This will avoid the problem you encountered instead of solving it.

The method you are looking for is `find_elements_by_xpath`, and the way to string several attributes using XPath would be something like: `//[@location or @title]`.

Comment: I just figured XPath would look better styled. I can see that you didn't like that, so I apologize.